# WebChat - Integration of Identification Language of Speech?

Tags: web-chat

Is it possible to integrate the language identification of speech (limit of four languages) in the speech recognition of the WebChat ?

Currently the user has to "select" their language, but I would like the bot to automatically detect their language when the user speaks.

Thank you very much :-)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of something like the [Language Detection API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/language-service/language-detection/quickstart?pivots=programming-language-csharp), which is part of Azure Cognitive Services. This service will examine a properly formatted string of text and return back the detected language and its ISO language code.

Perhaps you could, with your user's consent, take the first message they send after connecting to the bot and send it to the Language Detection service, and then use that result to set the language property instead of prompting the user? The quickstart I linked above has a super simple example (in C#) that you could integrate into your bot.